# How to setup localhost for making game

Tags: localhost

Recently, i am making a 2d game with quints,html5,tiled and javascript.i need a localhost as a output to display the scene,which local host should i use and how to set up one once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a webserver like Apache or Nginx.

If you're on a Windows PC, you can just download and install the [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) bundle.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention the M is for MySQL